# XML vs Array Performance

Tags: c#

From a performance standpoint, it is more beneficial to read large amounts of data from an XML file or by looping through an array?

I have around 2,000 datasets I need to loop through and do calculations with, so I'm just wondering if it would be better to import all XML data and process it as an array (single large import) or to import each dataset sequentially (many small imports).

Thoughts and suggestions?

Comment: "XML vs Array" is not really what you are asking. I advise you change your title.

Comment: What do your tests say?

Comment: @l4v - I haven't yet tested it, it will require a decent bit of code modification, just trying to gather some input at this point

Comment: @KirkWoll what would you suggest?

Comment: One method would be more expensive on IO (slower), and another on memory. If you have a huge XML file, I would consider slicing it. If you have a normally sized XML, I would read it in one go, and process the data in memory.

Comment: How about "single large import vs. many small imports"?

Comment: Think about trying a native XML database, they're optimized for working on large XML instances. Benefit depends on your data and access pattern, though. Some examples would be eXist, Sedna, Marklogic, BaseX.

Comment: Using vtd-xml, xml nodes are represented using array, so they are not mutually exclusive...

Answer (score 1):

If I have interpreted your question correctly, you need to load 2,000 sets of data from one file, and then process them all. So you have to read all the data and process all the data. At a basic level there is the same amount of work to do.

So I think the question is "How can I finish the same processing earlier?"

Consider:

How much memory will the data use? If it's going to be more than 1.5GB of RAM, then you will not be able to process it in a single pass on a 32-bit PC, and even on 64-bit PCs you're likely to see virtual memory paging killing performance. In either of these cases, streaming the data in smaller chunks is a necessity.

Conversely if the data is small (e.g. 2000 records might only be 200kB for all I know), then you may get better I/O performance by reading it in one chunk, or it will load so fast compared to the processing time that there is no point trying to optimise it.

Are the records independent? (so they don't need to be processed in a particular order, and you don't need one record present in memory in order to process another one) If so, and if the loading time is significant overall, then the "best" approach *may* be to parallelise the operation - If you can process some data while you are loading more data in the background, you will utilise the hardware better and do the same work in less time. So you probably want to consider splitting your loading and processing onto different threads.

But spreading the processing onto many threads might not help you if loading takes much longer than processing, as your processing threads may be starved of data while waiting for I/O - so using 1 processing thread may be just as fast as using 3 or 7. And there's no point in creating more threads than you have available CPU cores. If going multithreaded, I'd write it to use a configurable/dynamic number of threads and then do some testing to determine what the optimum approach will be.

But before you consider all of that, you might want to consider writing a brute force approach and see what the performance is like. Do you even *need* to optimise it?

And if the answer is "yes, I desperately need to optimise it", then can you reconsider the data format? XML is a very useful but grossly inefficient format. If you have a performance critical case, is there anything you can do to reduce the XML size (e.g. simply using shorter element names can make a massive difference on large files), or even use a much more compact and easily read binary format?

Comment: Some great input there, thanks...so one question...what is the optimal middle ground between XML and binary that maintains some level of human readability (binary is "readable", but you get the point) while being better optimized for programmatic use?

Comment: If you want human readable you cash use xml, but to make it faster to read, use a compact format. E.g. instead of "custonername" as an element tag, something like "cname", "cust" or "cn" might be "readable" but much shorter. Xml reading trends to be linear time relative to the size if the data, so halving file size usually halives loading time.